# XSLT: Convert base64 data into image files

Tags: xslt, file-io, image-processing, base64, evernote

I have seen several questions on how to encode an image file in base64, but how about the other way around - how do I reconstitute a picture from a base64 string stored in an XML file?

```
<resource>
<data encoding="base64">
R0lGODlhEAAQAPMAMcDAwP/crv/erbigfVdLOyslHQAAAAECAwECAwECAwECAwECAwECAwECAwEC
AwECAyH/C01TT0ZGSUNFOS4wGAAAAAxtc09QTVNPRkZJQ0U5LjAHgfNAGQAh/wtNU09GRklDRTku
MBUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAIf8LTVNPRkZJQ0U5LjATAAAAB3RJTUUH1AkWBTYSQXe8
fQAh+QQBAAAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADSQhgpv7OlDGYstCIMqsZAXYJJEdRQRWRrHk2I9t28CLfX63d
ZEXovJ7htwr6dIQB7/hgJGXMzFApOBYgl6n1il0Mv5xuhBEGJAAAOw==
</data>
<mime>image/gif</mime>
<resource-attributes>
    <file-name>clip_image001.gif</file-name>
</resource-attributes>
</resource>
```

Given the above XML node `resource`, how do I go about creating `clip_image001.gif`?

Please suggest:

1. XSLT processors and/or extensions enable this, plus
2. a sample XSLT that triggers the
   conversion

Note that it must be able to handle at least GIF & PNG file formats. Preferably not restricted to any OS.

---

## Implemented solution

Based around [Mads Hansen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14419/mads-hansen) solution. Main difference being that I referenced `net.sf.saxon.value.Base64BinaryValue` directly in my namespace rather than using the `saxon` namespace, because I understood the Java APIs more intuitively than the Saxonica website's descriptions of the `base64Binary-to-octets` and `base64Binary` functions.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:b64="net.sf.saxon.value.Base64BinaryValue"
    xmlns:fos="java.io.FileOutputStream"
    ...
    exclude-result-prefixes="b64 fos">
...
<xsl:for-each select="resource">                
    <xsl:variable name="b64" select="b64:new(string(data))"/>
    ...
    <xsl:variable name="fos" select="fos:new(string($img))"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="fos:write($fos, b64:getBinaryValue($b64))"/>  
    <xsl:value-of select="fos:close($fos)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
...
```

P.S. See [sibling question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684963/xslt-obtaining-or-matching-hashes-for-base64-encoded-data) for my implementation of how to obtain the hashes necessary to identify the image files.

---

This question is  a subquestion of [another question I have asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642104/evernote-export-format-enex-to-html-including-pictures).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[I found this entry from the XSL maiing lists](http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200710/msg00471.html) that describes how to use the **Saxon extension function *xs:base64Binary-to-octet*** to stream it out to a file using the Java FileOutputStream in an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform";
version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/";
xmlns:fos="java.io.FileOutputStream">
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="img" select="concat('c:\test\jesper', '.jpg')"/>
   <xsl:variable name="fos" select="fos:new(string($img))"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="fos:write($fos,
saxon:base64Binary-to-octets(xs:base64Binary(my-base64-encoded-image)))"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="fos:close($fos)"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I wanted, cos it's actually writing the images to external files.

Comment: I think it should be `saxon:base64Binary-to-octets` (with the trailing `s`). See http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions.html

Comment: Error: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: xs, on line xs:base64Binary(my-base64-encoded-image), **more** Extension function http://saxon.sf.net/ : base64Binary-to-octets is unknown

Comment: @Sarz I believe that is a premium feature and you either need the PE or EE version. http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/base64Binary-to-octets.html

Answer (score 7):

The following works:

```
<img>
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('data:image/gif;base64,',xPath)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

Comment: +1 @StrangeDays : Thanks for your answer! I'm not going to look into this (was a long time ago) anytime soon, but if it does indeed work, it does look like a much more neat & elegant solution than the other ones suggested here so far.

Comment: forgot a space there:
<xsl:value-of select="concat('data:image/gif;base64,',xPath)"/>

Comment: This is to generate HTML IMG element with BASE64 source. Not exactly an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Transform it to HTML.

```
<img src="data:{mime};base64,{data}" />
```

Comment: What XSLT processor and extensions do you use?

Comment: And I want to be able to actually generate the image files, that is create clip_image001.gif, and then in the output html get <img src="clip_image001.gif" />, because I need to generate a hash from the picture file as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better method available since Saxon 9.5 via the EXPath File extension module (available in Saxon-PE and Saxon-EE).

Here is a fragment of the code I'm using to extract binary image files from Word documents (source XML is in WordProcessingML format):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:file="http://expath.org/ns/file" xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">

<xsl:template match="/pkg:package">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="pkg:part/pkg:binaryData"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pkg:binaryData">
    <xsl:variable name="filename">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(../@pkg:name, '/word/media/', '')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="path" select="concat('/some/folder/', $filename)"/>
    <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$path"/></xsl:message>

    <xsl:value-of select="file:write-binary($path, xs:base64Binary(string()))"/>       
</xsl:template>
```