# How to output / display (in a HTML file) an image that is within each <Image> tag (in XML) with XSLT?

Tags: xml, image, xslt, xpath

Say I have an XML file with the following tag...

```
<pic> flower.jpg </pic>
```

I can transform my XML document into a HTML file using XSLT. However, my problem is HOW to output the actual image! All that displays in the browser is "flower.jpg", but obviously I want to see the actual picture!

What XSL code do I need so I can extract an image from every  tag in my XML!?

Do I need to change my XML as well to do this? All the images are in a local folder!

I was told this could be done with the  element in XSLT (linking to some "src" in the XML?). Is this possible?

Please help. Thank you. Edited...

Comment: Is the image actually in the XML (as a base64 encoded string) or does it just have the name?   If it is just the name you just need to create the image tag in your XSLT pointing to the image <IMG SRC="http:\\server\path\flower.jpg" />   If it is base64 encoded, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684909/xslt-convert-base64-data-into-image-files

Comment: It is just the name of the image. There is more than one image tag (each containing one image name), so how do you output all of them?

Comment: Then you need to do what Phil has answered.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but something like this in your for-each or template match for the `<pic>` tag

```
<img>
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```